# Is it ok to host multiple sites on a server with one IP address?

Tags: ip, hosting

I wonder if is it ok to host multiple sites on a server with one IP address?

I bought server on hetzner and I want to host 10 different websites of my clients. Eg. client1.com, client2.net, client3.org etc. I changed "A record" in all domains on IP address of my server. Is there any reasons to not do that? Or maybe I should buy additional IP address for each site?

Thank You.

Comment: `is it ok to host multiple sites on a server with one IP address?` Yes, this is commonly done.

Comment: Of course you can.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it is, your webserver will be able to filter requests to the correct site based on the incoming request's URL.

In Apache this is done by adding a new virtual host to your configuration.

Comment: Yup, I'm using Nginx so this is not a problem. I was afraid about some SSL problems or google robots.

Comment: SSL can be a problem: the browser and server both need to support Server Name Indication in order to work with virtual hosts.  The good news is that Nginx supports it, and the only major browsers that don't are Internet Explorer (any version) on XP, and Android before 3.0.